# Php loop function to cut and loop from post variable and execute different queries

Tags: php, sql, loops, foreach

I have a form that posts the following data:

```
$_POST['en_product_name']
$_POST['de_product_name']
$_POST['fr_product_name']
$_POST['ru_product_name']
```

what would be the best loop to cut language sign before `_product_name` and to execute query for each:

```
!empty($_POST['_product_name'])
```

Is this possible at all?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let me ask what have you tried.?

Comment: Nothing, have no idea where to start from..any clue is more than welcome..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach($_POST as $postKey => $postVal) {
    if(preg_match("/^(.*)_product_name$/i",$postKey)) {
        echo $postKey." = ".$postVal;
    }
}
```

Check these, [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

Comment: Also check the links included, so that you'll get a better idea of what it is.